# Use animation only on specific page(s) with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a problem with transitions using vue.js. I have a "Login" component that holds my login page. I would like to use an animation name="fade" only on that specific page (component). In my App.vue I have written:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="fade">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

I understand the problem. This animation applies on all pages inside router-view. Is there any solution to remove transition or even change the transition name to "none" after router-view redirects to another page?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not know to what extent it will be possible because the change of route is done after the animation and not before. Perhaps it would be easier for you to apply only the effect within the specific component that surrounds the router of a transition.